# Set basename to Domain/reactapp/#/home instead of Domain/#/reactapp/home

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am using **react-router** Hash Router instead of BrowserRouter. I have to **deploy my react app on server root inside sub-directory**. So that i can access my app by hitting **www.domain.com/reactapp**.

To Achieve that, I

1) Added homepage parameter in **package.json** directory
2) Added `<HashRouter basename={process.env.PUBLIC_URL}>`

Now, When I access my website by hitting **www.domain.com/reactapp**, I will be redirected to `www.domain.com/#/reactapp/home`.

But i want it to be redirected to `www.domain.com/reactapp/#/home/`.

**Note:** I am using react production build

How can i achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the documentation for basename, it appends the string **after** the hash symbol (which is not what you want):

https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/HashRouter/basename-string

If you remove basename, and your index.html is served from /reactapp - it may just work.

EDIT -

It does work: https://codesandbox.io/s/yj7znr2m1j

Comment: Can you please explain, what you want to say?

Comment: I am using react production build.

Comment: Can you please help me to solve problem mentioned in question?

Comment: see my sandbox example - files in /reactapp, no basename

Comment: Sir, It's seems to be a simple problem. But i am not able to understand why it's coming. I have so many routes in my app. And i have to deploy my reactapp in the sub-directory. For that, I need to set basename to sub-folder.

Comment: please help me, I a musing hash router. So it's making route localhost/#/reactapp instead of localhost/reactapp/#

Comment: dude - that's what Im saying - you DONT NEED basename - it does something different to what you think it does

Comment: try it, I hope so

Comment: what do i need to try?

Comment: As i already told you, I need to deploy my production build inside sub-directory.

Comment: So, I need to give basename.

Comment: So, How can i give?